# Date format using moments.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
this.state.date = "20190704153907"   
 moment(this.state.date).format("DD MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss")
```

I am getting Invalid date

I tried in different format stll showing same

Expected output:

```
4 July 2019 15:39:07
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date is indeed invalid. [Check the parsing docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

You can try to modify it via regex to match a known date pattern or equiv.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is the format i am getting from one of payment gateway

Comment: Not much reason to edit, the question is already answered. :-)

Comment: Noted the ks ;) @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the console, you'll see a warning from Moment:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

The format you're using for your date string is not the ISO format, and probably isn't supported by any of the *"implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats"*¹ that JavaScript engines are allowed to use to guess at what you meant.

The solution is to [tell Moment the format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```js
const date = "20190704153907";
const m = moment(date, "YYYYMMDDHHmmss");
console.log(m.format("DD MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that that outputs `04`, not `4` as in your expected output. If you want `4` instead of `04`, remove one of the `D` in your `format` string (e.g., `.format(..., "D MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss")`):

```js
const date = "20190704153907";
const m = moment(date, "YYYYMMDDHHmmss");
console.log(m.format("D MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

¹ https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse